# Reinstalling Windows 8 from Ubuntu 14.1

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, usb

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 which came with Windows 8.  I am not sure if it is UEFI, BIOS, MBR, etc. as I am a completely novice user, but I think these are important considerations from what I have gathered.

My first time trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, I accidentally removed Windows completely.  Before this attempt, I created the recovery USB stick with Windows, thinking that I can easily reinstall Windows 8 over Ubuntu if I made any mistakes.  This is proving to be trickier than I supposed.  Here is a clip of what my Windows 8 recovery USB contains:

[image]

I believe what is on my USB is a copy of the recovery partition from Windows.  I have not been able to find an .iso file here.

My hope is to reinstall Windows 8, completely wiping out Ubuntu, and then install Ubuntu alongside Windows the right way.

Comment: What you have there is a bootable WinRE disk.  It cannot be used to install Windows.  You need to download either `Windows 8.0` or `Windows 8.1` ( the version that came with your computer ) .ISO burn that to a disk and boot to that disk.  You need to figure out if you disk contains MBR partitions or GPT partitions currently in order to determine if you need to boot that disk using compatibility mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the original installation media to do this. You cannot install windows 8 through a recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

First change all those files into a bootable format and copy it in a USB. Later, once you plug the USB it may show you the option to boot from USB.

In windows there is a tool that helps you change those files into a bootable format. So using that tool you can do this.